# Insert function for a trie in Ocaml

Tags: beginner, trie, ocaml

I don't know how could I write smarter/more elegant code for the `add` function , it just seems so meaty and hard to read.
This trie only stores words and marks their end with a `bool`.

```
type trie = Node of bool * (char * trie) list 
let empty = Node (false, [])

let rec add w tr = match w, tr with 
    | [], Node (_, lvl_l) -> Node (true, lvl_l)
    | wh :: wt, Node (b, lvl_l) -> 
        try let ins_point = (List.assoc wh lvl_l) in  
        Node(b, (wh, add wt ins_point)::(List.remove_assoc wh lvl_l)) 
        with Not_found -> Node (b, (wh, add wt empty)::lvl_l)


let explode word = 
       let rec explode' i acc = 
           if i < 0 then acc else explode' (i-1) (word.[i] :: acc) 
            in explode' (String.length word - 1) []
```

Output Example :

```
# let x = add (explode "horror") empty;;
val x : trie =
  Node (false,
   [('h',
     Node (false,
      [('o',
        Node (false,
         [('r',
           Node (false,
            [('r',
              Node (false, [('o', Node (false, [('r', Node (true, []))]))]))]))]))]))])
# let x = add (explode "horrific") x;;
val x : trie =
  Node (false,
   [('h',
     Node (false,
      [('o',
        Node (false,
         [('r',
           Node (false,
            [('r',
              Node (false,
               [('i',
                 Node (false,
                  [('f',
                    Node (false,
                     [('i', Node (false, [('c', Node (true, []))]))]))]));
                ('o', Node (false, [('r', Node (true, []))]))]))]))]))]))])
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes just adding whitespace helps:

```
let rec add w tr = match w, tr with 
    | [], Node (_, lvl_l) ->
        Node (true, lvl_l)
    | wh :: wt, Node (b, lvl_l) -> 
        try
            let ins_point = List.assoc wh lvl_l in  
            Node (b, (wh, add wt ins_point)::(List.remove_assoc wh lvl_l)) 
        with Not_found ->
            Node (b, (wh, add wt empty)::lvl_l)
```

The `match` expression was upgraded in recent years to match on exceptions. So you can also do this:

```
let rec add w tr = match w, tr with 
    | [], Node (_, lvl_l) ->
        Node (true, lvl_l)
    | wh :: wt, Node (b, lvl_l) -> 
        begin match List.assoc wh lvl_l with
            | ins_point ->  
                Node (b, (wh, add wt ins_point)::(List.remove_assoc wh lvl_l)) 
            | exception Not_found ->
                Node (b, (wh, add wt empty)::lvl_l)
        end
```

(I had to wrap the `match` in a `begin`/`end` block to avoid confusing which `match` the patterns are applied.)

Since the return value has a common form, you could use `match` to just compute the second part of the pair:

```
let rec add w tr = match w, tr with 
    | [], Node (_, lvl_l) ->
        Node (true, lvl_l)
    | wh :: wt, Node (b, lvl_l) ->
        Node (b, match List.assoc wh lvl_l with
                 | ins_point ->  
                     (wh, add wt ins_point) :: (List.remove_assoc wh lvl_l) 
                 | exception Not_found ->
                     (wh, add wt empty) :: lvl_l)
```

It's subjective whether these are any better than your example. I do think, however, that visually showing the structure helps me understand the code better. For instance, my last version shows `Node` being produced in both match cases. You could elevate the constructor "one more level up" and have the nested `match` expressions compute the pair to apply to the constructor. This wasn't immediately obvious from your example.